# Retrieve part of structured data from POCOs C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<TerminalLink>` from which I want to retrieve a subset of. See the class structure below.

The subset is defined by a "map" which identifies which `ChannelLink` to select in any given scenario. Multiple `ChannelLink`s may be required per scenario, perhaps from the same `ChannelGroup`, perhaps from different `ChannelGroup`s on the same `TerminalLink`, and perhaps from multiple `TerminalLink`s in my original in memory list.

The ChannelLink can only be select if it's ChannelGroupLink and TerminalLink match too (they form part of the index, I guess).

I have tried various Linq and foreach approaches, but I'm running into tens of lines of code, which is ugly and difficult to follow. I'm sure there is an elegant approach.

How do I return a pruned `List<TerminalLink>` containing just the data that matches my map (i.e. containing only `TerminalLinks` and `ChannelGroupLinks` with required `ChannelLinks`)?

**Class structure:**

```
public class TerminalLink
{
    public string TerminalName { get; set; }
    public string TerminalType { get; set; }
    public ChannelGroupLink[] ChannelGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelGroupLink
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; } 
    public int ItemType { get; set; }
    public int SubType { get; set; }
    public ChannelLink[] Channels { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelLink
{
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }
    public string PathName { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public bool IsOutput { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT to include the latest attempt:**

```
public static List<TerminalLink> GetCompatibleChannelLinks(List<TerminalLinkMap> terminalLinkMaps, List<TerminalLink> asBuiltList)
{
    List<TerminalLink> matching = new List<TerminalLink>();

    var terminalsWithSomeMatchingChannelGroups = from terminal in asBuiltList
        from tlm in terminalLinkMaps
        where terminal.TerminalType == tlm.ItemSubTypeName
        from cgsMaps in tlm.ChannelGroupsToLink
        from cgs in terminal.ChannelGroups
        where cgsMaps.IsLinkMatch(cgs.GroupName, cgs.ItemType, cgs.SubType)
        select (
            link: new TerminalLink()
            {
                TerminalName = terminal.TerminalName,
                TerminalType = terminal.TerminalType
            },
            original: terminal, map: tlm
        );

    foreach (var possibleLink in terminalsWithSomeMatchingChannelGroups)
    {
        var linkCandidate = possibleLink.link;
        var originalData = possibleLink.original;
        var map = possibleLink.map;

        foreach (var cgs in originalData.ChannelGroups)
        {
            foreach (var channel in cgs.Channels)
            {
                // WIP
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2: inclusion of TeminalLinkMap**

```
public class TerminalLinkMap
{
    public string TerminalTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ItemSubTypeName { get; set; } // Match on this.
    public ChannelGroupToLink[] ChannelGroupsToLink { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelGroupToLink
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; } // regex match is ok.
    public int ItemType { get; set; }
    public int SubType { get; set; }
    public ChannelToLink[] Channels { get; set; }
    public ChannelGroupToLink GetClone() => GetClone(this);

    public bool IsLinkMatch(string groupName, int itemType, int subType)
    {
        return
        GroupName == groupName
        && ItemType == itemType
        && SubType == subType;
    }
}

public class ChannelToLink
{
    public int ItemType { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public int DataSizeInBits { get; set; }
    public bool IsOutput { get; set; }
    public ChannelToLink GetClone() => GetClone(this);

    public bool IsLinkMatch(string dataType, bool isOutput)
    {
        return
        DataType == dataType
        && IsOutput == isOutput;
    }

    public static ChannelToLink GetClone(ChannelToLink original) => new ChannelToLink()
    {
        ItemType = original.ItemType,
        DataType = original.DataType,
        DataSizeInBits = original.DataSizeInBits,
        IsOutput = original.IsOutput
    };
}
```

Comment: '`I have tried various Linq and foreach approaches,`' pls add your codes that you have tried.

Comment: @SelimYıldız added latest WIP, as requested.

Comment: Could you post the structure of `TerminalLinkMap`? Also what does `IsLinkMatch` do in terms of validation?

Comment: @devb included as requested. IsLinkMatch shown too - I don't mind losing that

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a join.

Try following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TerminalLink> asBuiltList = new List<TerminalLink>();

        List<TerminalLink> links = asBuiltList
                .Select(x => new { TerminalLink = x, ChannelGroups = x.ChannelGroups.Where(y => y.IsLinkMatch("Apple", 123, 456)) })
                .Where(x => x.ChannelGroups.Count() > 0)
                .Select(x => new TerminalLink() { TerminalName = x.TerminalLink.TerminalName, TerminalType = x.TerminalLink.TerminalType, ChannelGroups = x.ChannelGroups.ToArray()})
                .ToList(); 
        }
    }
    public class TerminalLink
    {
        public string TerminalName { get; set; }
        public string TerminalType { get; set; }
        public ChannelGroupLink[] ChannelGroups { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChannelGroupLink
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public int ItemType { get; set; }
        public int SubType { get; set; }
        public ChannelLink[] Channels { get; set; }

        public Boolean IsLinkMatch(string groupName, int itemType, int subType)
        {
            return (this.GroupName == groupName) && ( this.ItemType == itemType) && (this.SubType == subType);
        }
    }

    public class ChannelLink
    {
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }
        public string PathName { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public bool IsOutput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see where you are going, but this doesn't consider the list of TerminalLinkMap, doesn't include the ChannelLink, and doesn't return a ```List<TerminalLink>```. I can get to this depth of check (although your way is more elegant than mine - thanks), but including the channels is the trickier bit for me.

Comment: I made some changes

Comment: still not using a list of TerminalLinkMap to search for ChannelLink, and still not actually searching for the ChannelLink to match anything

Comment: You just changed the name in edit 2 from TerminalLink to TerminalLinkMap.  I'm matching on "apple, 123, 456.  Are you trying to group pairs or just do a search for fixed values?  It is not clear from your question.

Comment: The original question mentions the map, the first edit shows the map. I am trying to retrieve a ```List<TerminalLink>``` holding only Terminals, ChannelGroupLinks and ChannelLinks that match the map

Comment: Does the map include all the objects in the ChannelLink?  My code is matching group Name, item type, and sub item type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203250/discussion-between-mark-lazz-and-jdweng).